# Grunt serves up on port, but cannot access with remote machine

Tags: gruntjs

So my grunt file cooks up my site and runs it on a port on any machine (i.e. localhost:9000), but I cannot access that running page/site via machinename:9000. Had gotten a 502 error that didn't make sense. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cached on the client machine?

Comment: Correct, the browser cache has been cleared.

Comment: what do you use to serve your site? Please give exact task name and post configuration from Gruntfile.js